# Storage of medical records for a patient

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have 'n' patients and 'm' problems. The problems are of boolean type. Eg diabetes problem would be 'T' if a patient has it or 'F' otherwise. Suggest the data structure you would store this scenario on?

Q: We have a set of problems {diabetes, liver disease, kidney disease} find all the patients who have at least the 3 problems from the set.

The number of patients can be huge (n).

The number of problems not comparatively huge (m).

Which would be the best data structure to store these kind of  records, so that we have a better search time.

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: Im guessing this is homework. You need to post the code you have tried with a specific coding issue.

Comment: Its an interview question. Just to identify the approach. I dont need the code. Just the data structure. My suggestion was to use a hash table.

Comment: Ask him if you should be trying to optimize time or space. If they answer time, I would go with data cube. If they answer space, I like the hashtable idea (unless you want to throw time out the window). If they answer I dont know, you can safely cross the bridge. If they say both, get a blue police box.

Comment: The best data structure that i will use is the dynamic 2 dimensional array. For space and time its efficient. Space complexity is O(n+m) and the time complexity to find an element is constant.

Comment: How about using a bit map
#define NUM_OF_PATIENTS X
uint64 problemMap[NUM_OF_PATIENTS]; or
uint32 problemMap[NUM_OF_PATIENTS];
Assuming the number of problems are less than 64 or 32.
Each bit in the array represents the problems associated with that patient.

Comment: @ZeshanKhanAlvi while searching for one patient who has at least 3 diseases, won't you have to access all the disease columns in worst case. Making the time complexity for search of O(m*n)?

Comment: For this type of problem you may store number of disease with patient.